# How to float an element to right with fixed position and inside the <div> tag

Tags: html, css

I have tried Below html code

```
  <img src='close.png' style='float:right; position:fixed'>
```

But not working.. Image displaying at the center of `<div>`

Comment: Floating and fixed don't go together. What is it you are trying to do?

Comment: `position:fixed` is **always** in relation to the viewport...it will have nothing to do with the parent div.

Answer (score -1):

Make it like this:

```
  <img src="close.png" style="float:right; position:relative;">
```

Comment: Or just remove the `position` property completely...it's not doing anything.

Comment: It depends but just in this case yeah its true it's doing nothing :)

Comment: Exactly...an answer here, right now, is probably inappropriate since we have no clear idea of what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: Thats why i put it relative because when its fixed its also relative at first but fixed blocks the float working :)

Comment: I have no idea what that means. "When it's fixed it's also relative at first"...what?

Comment: When you position an element as fixed it also is relative to other elements.

Comment: fixed position elements are always in relation to the viewport, as Paulie_D mentioned